# I just started to write my program and noticed that self in definition is orange but the rest of the self's are red. I don't know why

Tags: python

I just started to write my program and noticed that self in definition is orange but the rest of the self's are red. I assume this means an error I just don't know why.

```py
class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self, master, title):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title = title
        self.master.geometry("1500x900")
        self.master.config(bg='#aad5df')
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your code. I assume the colours come from the IDE you are using. Which IDE would that be?

Comment: No issue here, just syntax highlighting. Typically errors or warnings have a red squiggly underline or it would be highlighted in yellow.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably just syntax highlighting m8, don't stress it. If they were errors or warnings they would have squiggly red or yellow underlines and your IDE or code editor of choice would let you know about it.